# How insert to database ID of user that connected?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert to database the id of current username that connected, how to get the id of my username from the query ?
i am trying to insert the new rows to the database and need the id of user that connected.

```
<?php
     require 'connect.inc.php';
     require 'core.inc.php';
    ?>
    <?php

    $username = "";
    if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)){

        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
        echo $query;
        if($query_run = mysqli_query($connect, $query)){
            $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows( $query_run);

        if($query_num_rows==0){
            echo 'Invalid username/password combination.';
        }else if ($query_num_rows==1){
         $_SESSION['username']=$username; 
         $_SESSION['password']=$password;
         $_SESSION['id']=$query_num_rows;

         header('Location: main.php');

        }

        }

        }else{
            echo 'You must supply a username and password.';

        }

    }

    if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
        if(isset($_POST["ch1"])){
        setcookie("unm",$_POST["username"],time()+3600);
        setcookie("pwd",$_POST["password"],time()+3600);
        }
        }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
    <input type= "checkbox" name="ch1" value="ch" />Remember username and password <br><br>
    <a href="removename_password.php">Remove username and password</a><br><br>
```

Comment: Why do you want to insert the current user connected into the database? (It's obvious it must be there already).

Answer (score 0):

Like so, if ID stores the id of the selected record:

```
if ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_run )) {

    $userID = $row["ID"];

}
```

Comment: I am trying to insert new rows in database, so i need the id of the user that connected to my system and creating new data, for insert his id to the new row with new data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I got:
Lets say you have a column named session_logged_in to store the current date and time in unix timestamp, then 
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `auth_user` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password' ORDER BY session_logged_in DESC LIMIT 0,1";